# how to overcome error in images array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to insert images (at present there are 7 images)into an array using a for loop and preview(display) those images in a scroll bar. the particular image from the scroll bar on click should appear in the given div.(the should be expanded to the size of the div)
this is for a certificate generator

this js code I tried[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWhlX.png) so far

```js
// var div = document.createElement("div");
// div.style.width = "300px";
// div.style.height = "300px";
// div.style.background = "red";
// document.getElementById("con").appendChild(div);
var image=  
[
  "themes/theme1.jpg",
  "themes/theme2.jpg",
  "themes/theme3.jpg",
  "themes/theme4.jpg",
  "themes/theme5.jpg",
  "themes/theme6.jpg",
  "themes/theme7.jpg"
];
var arrayLength=image.length;
var i;
var div = document.getElementById("main");
for (i =0;i<arrayLength;i++)
{
  var img=document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src",image[i]);
  img.setAttribute("width","100");
  img.setAttribute("height","100");
  img.addEventListener('click', function click(event) {
    console.log(img);
    document.getElementById('expandedImage').appendChild(img);
  },false);
  div.appendChild(img);
  // img = null;
}
// function myFunction(img) {
//   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
//   var main = document.getElementById("main");
//   expandImg.src = img.src;
//   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
// }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src='index.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="expandedImage" style="width:800px; height:500px;float:left; 
border: 1px solid black">
  </div>
  <!-- <div id="con"></div> -->
  <div id="main" style="width:150px; height: 500px; overflow-y: 
scroll;float:right"> 
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body
</html>
```

I expect the output to be the image I click on, but the actual output is the 7th image of my array

Comment: theres a random space between `themes/theme4.j` and 
`pg`

Comment: clean up your code, unless youve just copy and pasted it? theres so many issues with it like `-->html code>`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You can try to debug your code using F12 in your Browser

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `img` variable and your img variable have last created `img` element.

Instead of `img` `document.getElementById('expandedImage').appendChild(img);`

pass `this` to append click `image`.

`document.getElementById('expandedImage').appendChild(this);`

```js
var image = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg",
  "themes/theme2.jpg",
  "themes/theme3.jpg",
  "themes/theme4.jpg"
];
var arrayLength = image.length;
var i;
var div = document.getElementById("main");
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", image[i]);
  img.setAttribute("width", "100");
  img.setAttribute("height", "100");
  img.addEventListener('click', function click(event) {
    document.getElementById('expandedImage').appendChild(this);
  }, false);
  div.appendChild(img);
  // img = null;
}
```

```html
<div id="expandedImage" style="width:800px; height:500px;float:left; 
        border: 1px solid black">
</div>
<!-- <div id="con"></div> -->
<div id="main" style="width:150px; height: 500px; overflow-y: 
        scroll;float:right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending a new child to the `expandedImage` div why don't you create a new image tag inside expanded image div with the id as `expandedImage` and change the `src` of that image on each image scroll bar click.

Hope this helps.

Here is working [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yhzLerto/2/)

```js
// var div = document.createElement("div");
// div.style.width = "300px";
// div.style.height = "300px";
// div.style.background = "red";
// document.getElementById("con").appendChild(div);
var image=  
[ 
  "https://www.technology-solved.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/password-best-practices-image.png",
  "https://mycomputerexperts.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/webbrowsing.jpg",
  "https://www.royaloakindia.com/uploads/ROYIND-royaloak-amber-computer-table-small-800x50072.jpg"
];
var arrayLength=image.length;
var i;
var div = document.getElementById("main");
for (let i =0;i<arrayLength;i++)
{
  var img=document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src",image[i]);
  img.setAttribute("width","100");
  img.setAttribute("height","100");
  img.addEventListener('click', function click(event) {
    // console.log(img);
    document.getElementById('expandedImage').src = image[i];
  },false);
  div.appendChild(img);
  // img = null;
}

// Default image
document.getElementById('expandedImage').src = image[0];


// function myFunction(img) {
//   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
//   var main = document.getElementById("main");
//   expandImg.src = img.src;
//   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
// }
```

```css
#expandedWrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src='index.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="expandedWrapper">
    <img id="expandedImage" src="">
  </div>
  <!-- <div id="con"></div> -->
  <div id="main" style="width:150px; height: 500px; overflow-y: 
scroll;float:right"> 
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: I also need the image to fit exactly in the div (image should cover the whole div )without crops and repetitions

Comment: Are you talking about the scroll images or expanded images?

Comment: expanded image!

Comment: You can do this by small css. However, its updated you can check.

Comment: the expanded image should exactly fit in the div dimensions(the expanded image dimensions greater than the div is appearing bigger and the expanded image that is small is appearing in another dimension) I need all the expanded images in the size of div

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this was a problem is because JS has something called "hoarding". Basically if you write this:

```
if (true) {
    var x = 4;
}
```

It becomes this:

```
var x;
if (true) {
    x = 4;
}
```

To fix this you can use `let` insead of `var`

```js
// var div = document.createElement("div");
// div.style.width = "300px";
// div.style.height = "300px";
// div.style.background = "red";
// document.getElementById("con").appendChild(div);
var image=  
[
  "themes/theme1.jpg",
  "themes/theme2.jpg",
  "themes/theme3.jpg",
  "themes/theme4.jpg",
  "themes/theme5.jpg",
  "themes/theme6.jpg",
  "themes/theme7.jpg"
];
var arrayLength=image.length;
var i;
var div = document.getElementById("main");
for (i =0;i<arrayLength;i++)
{
  let img=document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src",image[i]);
  img.setAttribute("width","100");
  img.setAttribute("height","100");
  img.addEventListener('click', function click(event) {
    console.log(img);
    document.getElementById('expandedImage').appendChild(img);
  },false);
  div.appendChild(img);
  // img = null;
}
// function myFunction(img) {
//   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
//   var main = document.getElementById("main");
//   expandImg.src = img.src;
//   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
// }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src='index.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="expandedImage" style="width:800px; height:500px;float:left; 
border: 1px solid black">
  </div>
  <!-- <div id="con"></div> -->
  <div id="main" style="width:150px; height: 500px; overflow-y: 
scroll;float:right"> 
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body
</html>
```